# Slice returns full string rather than first num characters

Tags: javascript, string, slice

The string is not being sliced. The full string is being returned, rather than just the first `num` characters.

```js
function truncateString(str, num) {
      if (str.length > num) {
        str.slice(0,num)
        return str
      } else {
        return str
      }
}

console.log(truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8))
```

Comment: _"The slice() method extracts a section of a string and **returns it as a new string, without modifying the original string**."_

Comment: [Slice returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), it does not mutate the passed in string

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result of the slice method:

```js
function truncateString(str, num) {
      if (str.length > num) {
        return str.slice(0,num)
      } else {
        return str
      }
}

console.log(truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8))
```